# Ionic 3/Angular 2 - Renderer2.setValue() doesn't update the value of my input field

Tags: angular, ionic2

I'm trying to update the value of an input that isn't bound to a `<form>` in my component, and my research has lead me to use the `Renderer2` service that Angular provides.

So I have my input that looks like this:

```
<input type="text" #zipEl placeholder="Enter zip">
<button type="button" (click)="getLocation()">
   <span>Use current location</span>
</button>
```

And in my component, I'm trying to just set the value simply like this:

```
@ViewChild('zipEl') zipEl:ElementRef;

constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {

}

getLocation() {
    this.renderer.setValue(this.zipEl, '94085');
}
```

Though nothing is happening. When I click the button to run the function, the input box never gets its value updated with `94085`. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 22):

I believe you need to use `setProperty`:

```
getLocation() {
    this.renderer.setProperty(this.zipEl.nativeElement, 'value', '94085');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Angular v4.0.2, I ended up using the `.setAttribute()` function shown here:

```
getLocation() {
    this.renderer.setAttribute(this.zipEl, 'value', '94085');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your angular version ?

I do not yet find in which version is Renderer2

But it work with Renderer :

```
  @ViewChild('zipEl') zipEl:ElementRef;
  constructor(public renderer: Renderer) {
  }


  getLocation() {
    this.renderer.setElementAttribute(this.zipEl.nativeElement, 'value', '94085');
  }
```

Comment: You gave me an idea. I'm currently using Angular v4.0.2. I looked into the docs a bit more for Renderer2 and I found I could use `setAttribute`, instead of `setElementAttribute` and it worked :) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like this:

```
  constructor(element: ElementRef, renderer: Renderer2) {
    const input = renderer.createElement('input');
    renderer.setAttribute(input, 'value', '94085');
    renderer.listen(input, 'keyup', (ev) => {
      console.log(ev);
    });
    renderer.appendChild(element.nativeElement, input);
  }
```